# Look for a list of specific characters using RegEx

Tags: postgresql, regex

I'm trying to write a query (Postgres 8.2.15) which is checking whether the value in column1 consists of:

1. *English alphabet only* (A-Z), there should be no specific characters with umlaut/ablaut coming from Spanish, Arabic, German etc.
2. *Single space*, *dot*, *dash*, *ampersand*, *apostrophe*, *brackets* and *pipe* are allowed.

I have the below code which is working fine for *space*, *dot* and *dash* but when I insert some of the other symbols into the list the query is not producing the correct results:

```
select
    column1,
    case 
        when column1 !~ '^.*[^A-Za-z0-9 .-].*$'
        then 'ok' 
        else 'not ok' 
        end as "check",
from 
    table1
```

How can I expand the list with *ampersand*, *apostrophe*, *brackets* and *pipe*?

Comment: Postgres 8.2? Really? That has been unsupported for nearly a decade now. You should really plan an upgrade as soon as possible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your SQL is as follows:

```
when column1 !~ '^.*[^A-Za-z0-9 .-].*$'
```

This would be better written as

```
WHEN column1 !~ '[^A-Za-z0-9 .-]+'
```

So, only ASCII strings with the letters, digits and spaces, full stops (periods) and hyphens.

You can check out the long version below, but if you want to have `ampersand, apostrophe, brackets and pipes` to be allowed. - just use the (`\`) backslash escape character - you can change your pattern above to:

```
WHEN column1 !~  '[^A-Za-z0-9&\(\)\| \''.-]+'
```

The double apostrophe is to escape it further, since it's the pattern delimiter.

I created a table as follows (all the code below is available on the fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.5&fiddle=332b2aeedd812080665bc60d41d4ddf0) - it's 9.5 - that's the oldest version that I could find):

```
CREATE TABLE str_test
(
  str TEXT NOT NULL
);
```

and then entered some data as follows:

```
INSERT INTO str_test VALUES
('$ff asfd &*$'), 
('xyz asfd abc'), 
('abc 1234 agg'), 
('adf اشكرك agg'),            -- Arabic characters 
('The essential thing is'),
('afda sfsáásfd sdfs'),       -- á - a acute
('afda sfs谢谢你 sfd sdfs'),  -- Chinese characters
('adf (((( &*$'), 
('adf ||| &*$'),
('Rindfleischetikettierungsüberwachungsaufgabenübertragungsgesetz'), -- German word
('afasdfsdfdadfdsf fasfsafsdafasdfasfaadsf');
```

Now, your original pattern is `'^.*[^A-Za-z0-9 .-].*$'` so, I'll run it using the [`SUBSTRING()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/functions-matching.html) function. The strings which appear where will be `false` for the `!~` pattern matching operator - it's sometimes clearer if you spell out the string!

```
SELECT 
  SUBSTRING (str, '^.*[^A-Za-z0-9 .-].*$') FROM str_test;
```

Result:

```
substring
$ff asfd &*$
NULL
NULL
adf اشكرك agg
NULL
afda sfsáásfd sdfs
afda sfs谢谢你 sfd sdfs
adf (((( &*$
adf ||| &*$
Rindfleischetikettierungsüberwachungsaufgabenübertragungsgesetz
NULL
11 rows
```

So, what the pattern is doing is picking out all characters that are not alphnumerics (ASCII alphas) and then returning the entire string - this is because of the `^.*` and the `.*$` - everything before and after.

If you don't want the pipes and brackets, you can do the following:

```
SELECT
  SUBSTRING (str, '^.*[^A-Za-z0-9&\* .\|\$\(-]') FROM str_test;
```

Result:

```
substring
NULL
NULL
NULL
adf اشكرك
NULL
afda sfsáá
afda sfs谢谢你
Rindfleischetikettierungsüberwachungsaufgabenü
NULL
11 rows
```

So, we can see that the only strings that match the pattern are now the ones containing the Arabic characters, the `á` (a acute character), the Chinese characters and the German umlauts.

The `&`, `|`, `$`, `*` and bracket characters are now eliminated - this is done by putting the escape backslash (`\`) character before them (apart from the `&` which is not a regular expression [meta-character](https://www.regular-expressions.info/characters.html) - or special character).

Now, there is the `\w` meta-character-class (also known as a [shorthand class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/refcharclass.html)) - it stands for words -

```
SELECT
  SUBSTRING (str, '[^\w &\.\-\$\|\(\)\*]') FROM str_test;
```

Result:

```
substring
谢
12 rows
```

All `NULL` except for the Chinese characters - the Arabic and the a acute and the German are eliminated - there's only the Chinese to be tackled. So, I investigated and found [this page](https://developpaper.com/regular-expressions-match-both-chinese-and-english-as-well-as-common-regular-expressions/) which suggested that `\u4e00-\u9fa5` singled out Chinese characters

I decided to look at Japanese - this is the Japanese for thanks: `有り難う`.

```
INSERT INTO str_test VALUES ('有り難う');
```

I also went [here](https://gist.github.com/terrancesnyder/1345094) - and got the codes for Katekana/Hiragana...

So, the final code is

```
SELECT
  SUBSTRING (str, '[^\u3000\u3400-\u4DBF\u4E00-\u9FFFぁ-んァ-ン\w &\.\-\$\|\(\)\*]') FROM str_test;
```

Result:

```
substring
...
... all NULL
...
13 rows
```

Now, it's not very clear from your question what, exactly, you wish to return as OK - you appear to not want very much to be OK.

Here is [another fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.5&fiddle=da54e4cc4977697260b90078208f97a0) with several trials of mine - look at them and make sure that you understand what's going on - regular expressions are very powerful but they are also tricky - it can be difficult to figure out exactly what's going on!